# Attempt to subtract with overflow

Tags: rust

I am testing my binary search and I found this error. My question is why is the index unable to change even though I allow the variable to be mutable? Is the problem have to do with having types?

```
failures:

---- tests::test_binary_search stdout ----
thread 'tests::test_binary_search' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', src/lib.rs:77:19
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    tests::test_binary_search

test result: FAILED. 5 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.00s

error: test failed, to rerun pass '--lib'
```

This is my code and I marked line 77 has it has stated.

```
pub fn binary_search(arr: &[i32], query: i32) -> Option<usize> {
    let mut end = arr.len() - 1;
    let mut start = 0;

    while start <= end {
        let mid = ((end - start) /2 ) + start;
        let mid_index = mid as usize;

        let val = arr[mid_index];

        if val == query {
            return Some(mid_index);
        }

        if val < query {
            start = mid + 1;
        }

        // Search values that are less than val - to the left of current mid_index
        if val > query {
            end = mid - 1;  ERROR HERE
        }

        
    }

    return None;
}
```

Here is my test code.

```
 #[test]
    fn test_binary_search() {

        let arr: [i32; 12] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 101, 1000];

        assert_eq!(binary_search(&arr, 3).unwrap(), 2);
        assert_eq!(binary_search(&arr, 0), None);
        assert_eq!(binary_search(&arr, 101).unwrap(), 11);
        assert_eq!(binary_search(&arr, 1000).unwrap(), 11);


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default rust panics when you subtract with overflow on an unsigned type. (It won't panic if you run it with the `--release` flag)

```rs
fn main() {
    let mut x: u32 = 0;
    x = x - 1;
    println!("value: {}", x);
}
```

when you do

```rs
let mut end = arr.len() - 1;
```

`arr.len()` returns an `usize` thus everything becomes an `usize`. If you want to override this you can cast the value:

```rs
let len = (x.len() - 1) as isize;
```

Comment: I didn't realize that .len() returns a usize haha. Thank you that fixed it.

Comment: In this case, `arr.len().saturating_sub(1)` would probably be more appropriate than casting as `isize`.

Answer (score 0):

It is no good practice to ignore a possible overflow.
With `wrapping_sub()` the result here is `u32::MAX`. A more convenient way to check for overflow is to use `overflowing_sub()`, which returns a tuple consisting of the value `u32::MAX` and a boolean `true` for overflow:

```
fn main() {
    let x: u32 = 0;
    let (r, b) = x.overflowing_sub(1);
    println!("value: {r}, overflow: {b}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f936ed0c3b36868db6bf2dbc4b165acb)